# Writing a Script or a sentence using using cell values in Python

Tags: python, google-sheets

I'm just starting out learning python as I think it would help me automate some things during my work. So I needed a help to do one of those things. I have a google sheet with various details mentioned in the columns, for example, in the first column I have 'Name', 'Date of Birth' in the second, 'Class' in the third and 'Likes' in the fourth.
I want to be able to write a code which will combine these values to create a sentence for eg. My Name is 'Name'. My Date of Birth is 'Date of Birth'. I belong to Class 'Class'. I like 'Likes'.

I know I can do this using the concatenate formula in the sheet but my actual data is quite large involving more than 10 columns and 1000s of rows. So since I was learning Python I thought there  would be a way to do this in one go using Python which will save so much of my time. Thank you for reading, I would really appreciate if someone would guide me in doing this.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Read this [mre]

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear how you plan to fetch the data from the spreadsheet. To make the whole thing simpler, you could do the string concatenation using a spreadsheet formula, then fetch only the final result using Python.

Assuming the data is in the range `A2:D`, put this formula in row `2` of a free column:

```
=map( 
  A2:A, B2:B, C2:C, D2:D, 
  lambda( 
    name, date, class, likes, 
    if( 
      len(name), 
      join( 
        ". ", 
        "My Name is " & name, 
        "My Date of Birth is " & date, 
        "I belong to Class " & class, 
        "I like " & likes & "." 
      ), 
      iferror(1/0)  
    ) 
  ) 
)
```